# VB.NET Obtain a specific string from Multiple Text Files from a specified folder

Tags: vb.net, file

I just started learning VBnet today.

Here's the situation:

I have a folder that contains text files (about 100) named data1 data2 etc..

Each file contains a serial number:

example:

In data1.txt

HSB1 Serial Number 111222

In data2.txt

HSB1 Serial Number 987632

etc..

I made a VB.Net program that lets the user specify the folder location of the txt files using FolderBrowserDialog.

What I don't know is how to do is display the serial numbers only in a textbox.

The command should be done when I click the execute button. Thanks in advance!

So far this is what I have, I'm sorry I am very new to this but I have to make this program asap.

Public Class Form1

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = True
    If (folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath
        Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Execute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Execute.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Every file contains just one line of data and each line is formatted as explained above?

Answer (score 1):

This sample should work if your files have just one line of text and each line is formatted as you have explained above

```
Dim fileList = Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.txt", false)
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
For Each fileName in fileList
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    if lines.Length > 0 then
        Dim part = lines[0].Split(" "c)
        if part.Length > 2 Then
            sb.AppendLine(part(3))
        End If
    End If
Next
TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString()
```

TextBox2 is the textbox where you want to show the results of your search. It should have its property MultiLine set to True and a vertical Scrollbar (use the designer to set them)

The code use the some static methods like [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx) and File.[ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and an instance of the class [StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) to buffer all reads with just one append to the destination TextBox

Answer (score 0):

This Code should work, If the pattern of the file name and the serial number are same as you given in your question,

```
  Private Sub Execute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Execute.Click

     For Each xFile In Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.txt", false)
         'Textbox2 is the resultant textbox.
         TextBox2.Text &= space(2) & File.ReadAllLines(xFile)(0).Substring(File.ReadAllLines(xFile)(0).Length - 6, 6)
     Next

    End Sub
```

**EDITED** According to your comment: `The one that I gave is just the first line.`

Comment: I'm sorry to add this but in a text file it contains a lot more of information. The one that I gave is just the first line. There are more strings that I need to get such as time, sentences etc.

Comment: Does that serial number having any specific identity while comparring with the other texts in that file.?

Comment: I have tested this code in my system, it is running as expected, what about you? Did you test this in your environment.? :)

Comment: What is that error saying.? whether it is a runtime or compiletime error.?